# Find values in 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

I would like to do the equivalent of

```
x = [1, 0, 3; 2, 3, 0; 0, 0, 3];
[yy, xx, vals] = find(x);
```

where I really need the `vals` variable. I need all three, but `vals` is important. Now consider the 3d case, and flip one, so it's more interesting.

```
x = repmat(x, [1, 1, 3]);
x(:, :, 2) = fliplr(x(:, :, 1));
```

I'd like to do the same as before. I found this in several places

```
[yy, xx, zz] = ind2sub(size(x), find(x));
```

but then I don't know how to extract `vals` properly... I also don't really care about `zz`, but I'm sure they somehow need to be used for indexing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` with one output argument, as you used in your last statement:

```
[yy, xx, zz] = ind2sub(size(x), find(x));
```

returns linear indices into the matrix. You can use these to index:

```
index = find(x);
vals = x(index);
[xx,yy,zz] = ind2sub(size(x), index);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Also better than the other answer because no loops :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I've understood what you want to achieve, nevertheless, considering your last matrix `x`

```
x = [1, 0, 3; 2, 3, 0; 0, 0, 3]
z = repmat(x, [1, 1, 3]);
x(:, :, 2) = fliplr(x(:, :, 1))
```

with

```
[yy, xx, vals] = find(x)
```

you have:

- `yy` the indices of the rows of the found elements
- `xx` the indices of the columns of the found elements

then you can use

```
lin_idx=sub2ind(size(x),yy,xx)
```

to get the linear indices of the values inside the matrix `x`

now you can use

```
[a,b,c]=ind2sub(size(x),lin_idx)
```

to get the 3D indices of the elements in the matrix

You can access the values using that indices:

```
for i=1:length(a)
   k(i)=x(a(i),b(i),c(i))
end
```

Now the array `k` contains the values (as per the array `vals` returned by `find`).

Comment: Thanks, while this works, it uses a for loop, which are notoriously slow, as opposed to indexing. Thanks anyways!